# Creating a list of objects in Python constructor

Tags: python, constructor

I would like to pass a variable into the constructor of an object and depending upon the value get one or more more objects out. Something like:

```
class MyClass():

    def __init__(self,n_objects):

        #Should return n_objects of MyClass
```

Something doesn't seem quite right about it though since I need to return a list (I think) but self is of type "MyClass". What am I missing?

Comment: Instead of doing this in `__init__`, make a separate function (or possibly a classmethod) that returns either one instance or several instances.

Comment: @BrenBarn, point noted. I should mention I'm coming from a background in Matlab where there is an awful constructor kluge which allows returning an array of objects instead of just one, but it is all of the same class (not a list). In Java I've seen the class that is called be just a wrapper to calling another class multiple times, which I've never really liked, i.e. in my example you might have MyClass.MyObjects where MyObjects is really what I would want. If I wanted to do this as you suggest, what is the standard naming convention or strategy so that it is obvious to others?

Comment: I don't know of any naming convention specific to this; it's not something I've seen done often.  I would name the function according to its purpose, e.g., `getFoobarResult`, where knowing what "foobar" is means you know you might get one or more results.  But there's no substitute for documenting it so people can see what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A constructor only returns a single reference of what you are trying to create, so you can't do it this way.  What you need is to make this list external from this:

```
result = [MyClass() for i in xrange(n_objects)]
```

Then make a wrapper function around that.

Do note that `xrange` is for python 2, it was renamed to `range` in python 3.

If you must insist on keeping the "encapsulation" of the class, you can just define a classmethod.  Naive example:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.bar = 1
...     @classmethod
...     def Copies(cls, n):
...         return [cls() for i in xrange(n)]
... 
>>> Foo()
<__main__.Foo object at 0x7f2059ac1910>
>>> Foo.Copies(3)
[<__main__.Foo object at 0x7f2059ac19d0>, <__main__.Foo object at 0x7f2059ac1990>, <__main__.Foo object at 0x7f2059ac1a10>]
```

Comment: This seems to lose the encapsulation that the class contains. Perhaps my simple example is a bit misleading with having n_objects as an input. That was simply meant to illustrate that I wanted multiple objects out ....

Comment: Or do you want your objects to be "indexable"? i.e. `MyClass(5)[2]` giving you the third element of something inside the result of `MyClass(5)`?  Better question is: why are you doing this, why do you need this, and what exactly are you trying to achieve?